# How to access JSON object in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access JSON object in JavaScript file but in meantime it give me an error that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. I am new to JavaScript could some please help me how to solve this problem. I will also share JSON and JS file code you may explore code there.

**Main.JS**

```
 import Lang from "./lang";

console.log(Lang["dashboard.paragraph"]);
```

**Lang.JS**

```
 module.exports = {
  /* 01.Dashboard */
  "dashboard.title": "Dashboard",
  "dashboard.paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page",
};
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run this? Node.js? Browser?

Comment: JSON cannot contain comments, and no trailing commas.

Comment: @David784 I am trying in browser

Comment: This is NOT a JSON object. It is a JavaScript file that exports a JavaScript object. A valid JSON file would not include `module.exports`

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports = {
  /* 01.Dashboard */
  "dashboard.title": "Dashboard",
  "dashboard.paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page" // removed trailing comma(,) from here
};
```

Remove ',' after last key value pair. You can use jsonlint or any other JSON linting tool to validate your JSON object. You are getting this error because of invalid JSON object.

Comment: Can you please make a program or do some changes in my program

Comment: Yes, the comma needs to be removed. But this is NOT a JSON object. It is a JavaScript file that exports a JavaScript object. A valid JSON file would not include `module.exports`.

Comment: @Intervalia Samri is trying to access JSON object from a js file not a JSON file.

Comment: He may think he is, but if the file starts with `module.exports` then it is not a JSON file, it is a JavaScript file. If he wan't a true JSON then then he needs to remove the comments and the `module.exports = `.

Comment: @Intervalia Yes and will also need to use .json instead of .js if he want to use real JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two module formats. One is ES6 modules and the other is CommonJS.

You also had a filename with the first letter capitalized `Lang.js` and importing `./lang` in all lower case. The case should always match.

If you want to use ES6 modules then you need this:

**Main.JS**

```
import Lang from "./Lang";
console.log(Lang["dashboard.paragraph"]);
```

**Lang.JS**

```
export default {
  /* 01.Dashboard */
  "dashboard.title": "Dashboard",
  "dashboard.paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page"
};
```

And if you want to use Common JS then do this:

**Main.JS**

```
const Lang = require("./Lang");
console.log(Lang["dashboard.paragraph"]);
```

**Lang.JS**

```
module.exports = {
  /* 01.Dashboard */
  "dashboard.title": "Dashboard",
  "dashboard.paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `json` notation on yor file and a `XMLHttpRequest` object to open it.

```js
//Consider use this format to your file
let file = {
  /* 01.Dashboard */
  "dashboard.title": "Dashboard",
  "dashboard.paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page",
}

//here is the result
console.log(file);

//use XMLHttpRequest object to open from a file hosted with your app 
let fileOnLik;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(oReq.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(oReq.status === 200 || oReq.status == 0)
            {
                fileOnLik = oReq.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
oReq.open("get", "/folder/yourFile.json", true); //could be http://www.otherserver.com/yourFile.json
oReq.send();

console.log(fileOnLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any error with your approach. Moreover, having dot(.) in object property name is not a good programming practice.

You could write your JSON as below -

```
module.exports = {
        /* 01.Dashboard */
      "dashboard" : {
                "title": "Dashboard",
                "paragraph": " Here you will put data related to Dashboard Page"
      }
}
```

Comment: @Samri You will also need to replace `Lang["dashboard.paragraph"]` with `Lang.dashboard.paragraph`, modify your code only if you are not bounded to use dot within keys in your object.